Mind-boggingly Random, Intermittent SSL Verification Issues in PHP `file_get_contents` for HTTPS URLs
I'm encountering intermittent SSL verification issues when using file_get_contents in PHP to access multiple HTTPS URLs.
When I try to individually test URLs that fail, such as https://getcomposer.org/versions,with:
<?php
$options = [
    "ssl" => [
        "cafile" => "C:\\xampp\\php\\cacert.pem",
        "verify_peer" => true,
        "verify_peer_name" => true,
    ]
];
$context = stream_context_create($options);
echo file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/versions', false, $context);
?>

I receive the following errors:
// Error output: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed in C:\Users\HP\test.php on line 10

Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed in C:\Users\HP\test.php on line 10 PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in C:\Users\HP\test.php on line 10

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in C:\Users\HP\test.php on line 10 PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/versions): Failed to open stream: operation failed in C:\Users\HP\test.php on line 10

Warning: file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/versions): Failed to open stream: operation failed in C:\Users\HP\test.php on line 10

```

So, for debugging purposes I created a script to check multiple domains:
<?php
$options = [
    "ssl" => [
        "cafile" => "C:\\xampp\\php\\cacert.pem",
        "verify_peer" => true,
        "verify_peer_name" => true,
    ]
];

$context = stream_context_create($options);

// List of domains to check
$domains = [
    'https://google.com',
    'https://youtube.com',
    'https://example.com',
   // 27 more domains
];

$working_domains = [];
$non_working_domains = [];

foreach ($domains as $domain) {
    $response = @file_get_contents($domain, false, $context);

    if ($response !== false) {
        $working_domains[] = $domain;
    } else {
        $non_working_domains[] = $domain;
    }
}

// Output results
echo "Working Domains:\n";
foreach ($working_domains as $working) {
    echo $working . "\n";
}

echo "\nNon-Working Domains:\n";
foreach ($non_working_domains as $non_working) {
    echo $non_working . "\n";
}
?>

The script outputs a list of working and non-working domains. Here are the results:
Working Domains:
https://google.com
https://youtube.com
https://www.facebook.com
https://twitter.com
https://www.amazon.com
https://www.microsoft.com
https://www.mozilla.org
https://www.wikipedia.org
https://www.quora.com

Non-Working Domains:
https://example.com
https://getcomposer.org
https://www.bbc.com
https://www.cnn.com
https://www.reuters.com
https://www.instagram.com
https://www.ebay.com
https://www.alibaba.com
https://www.harvard.edu
https://www.stanford.edu
https://www.mit.edu
https://www.apple.com
https://www.github.com
https://www.netflix.com
https://www.spotify.com
https://www.dropbox.com
https://www.cloudflare.com
https://www.w3.org
https://www.random.org
https://example.org
https://www.linkedin.com

I am absolutely losing my mind. There does not seem to be any rhyme nor reason to which domains pass and fail. I suspect the issue might be related to SSL certificate verification, but I'm not sure how to diagnose it further. I've already ensured that the cacert.pem file is up-to-date and correctly referenced.
What could be causing some HTTPS URLs to fail while others work, and how can I resolve this issue?

My speculation is that there is some firewall or similar in your unknown environment which SSL intercepts some sites but not others. With SSL interception the certificate be re-issued by the firewall/proxy/antivirus and thus certificate validation failes unless you have the firewall CA as trusted in your cacert.pem

@SteffenUllrich yeah it was dumbass avg

I discovered that my AVG antivirus was causing issues with curl SSL connections on my local machine. Even after disabling enhanced firewall protection, I still experienced problems until I completely uninstalled AVG. This resolved the issue.
